# drive drools rule with complex compare to extract result from object with collection

Tags: java, arraylist, filter, drools

I have java classes as below

```
{
  private String name;
  private String employment;
  private ArrayList<Address> addresses;

//getter and setters
}

public  class Address{
  String addressType;
  String addressChangeDate; //apologies, this is in String
  String state;

 //getter and setters
}
```

I want to create Drools rule (java dialect) where Customer Object is input & returned object is filtered addresses list .
 **AFTER** filtering those addresses whose (addressType='Home' and state is in ('Kansas','IOWA'))

**IF** he has employment type ('Self','business') and has any other address(es) with addressType='Work' and (the addressChangeDate<90 days for addressType='Work')

```
rule "rule 1"
when
    $customer : Customer(addresses!=null, employment == ("Self","business"))
    $addressesOutput : List() from collect ( Addresses(length > 0, (addressType!='Home' && state in ('Kansas','IOWA'))) from $customer.addresses )
then
    insert($addressesOutput)
end
```

Please help to create the .drl file. 
I am pretty new to drools